# What's the curl's unit means when download a file?

Tags: curl

When I use curl testing a file download traffic rate:

```
curl -vo 1 'https://demo.com/apk/202112/008/93cd5df7dbf9385f6a12c720c8c5b360.apk'
```

I get:

```
{ [data not shown]
  2 1771M    2 50.5M    0     0  3591k      0  0:08:25  0:00:14  0:08:11 6153k
```

Is `6153k` means 6153kBps or 6153kbps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The manual page for curl(1) says:](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html)

> ##### PROGRESS METER
>
> curl normally displays a progress meter during operations, indicating the  amount  of
> transferred  data,  transfer  speeds and estimated time left, etc.
>
> The progress meter
> displays number of bytes and the speeds are in bytes per second.
>
> The suffixes (k,  M,
> G, T, P) are 1024 based. For example 1k is 1024 bytes. 1M is 1048576 bytes.